# How would I split this complex string into an String array?

Tags: java

I have a text file that I have to read and there was this complex string that I have to store into a String array. I have read about regex, but would really like if someone could help me understand how a complex string such as this could be broken into tokens and stored in an array

```
String sentence = "I said, "Mr. Jones’ golf 'golden' clubs were broken"."
```

Maybe using

```
scanner.next()
```

And then removing each of those punctuation marks, but how would I end up doing that?

The final array i'd like an array that looks like the

```
Array words[] = {"I", "said", "Mr", "Jones", "golf", "golden", "clubs", "were", "broken"};
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: I should point out that there is a possible flaw in your requirements.  Would you want `"Don't do it."` to turn into 4 "words"?  Neither "don" or "t" are (common) English words.

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the `String` using delimiter *One or mulitple non-word char* (`\W+` in regex)

   ```
   sentence.split("\\W+")
   ```
2. Result

   ```
   String sentence = "I said, \" Mr.Jones’golf 'golden' clubs were broken \".";
   String[] words = sentence.split("\\W+");

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));

   /*  [I, said, Mr, Jones, golf, golden, clubs, were, broken]
   ```

Comment: Why not split on non-word tokens to begin with? `sentence.split("\\W+")` ?

Comment: Thank oh so much.   Poria Edalat

Comment: @PoriaEdalat you're welcome, you can now think about vote up/accept an answer if iit satisfies your question

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways in which regex works. In your case, you have a String as input and want a String[] as output. This is a common requirement and regex has direct support for it. You only need to specify what are your token separators.

In your sample string, separators would be space, comma, dot, and quotation marks. These can pile up together in many ways, so a class match in the form of [ ] is needed.

So

```
String[] result = sentence.split("[ ,.\"']+");
```

In general, however, you'd want to consider other characters as separators as well, like tabs, newlines, etc. For that there is a predefined class \W, which is defined as all characters except a to z, A to Z and 0 to 9.

```
String[] result = sentence.split("\\W+");
```